# No available formula with the name "swiftlint"

Tags: homebrew, swiftlint

Im try to install SwiftLint via homebrew but got this error.

I make some searching on google but can't find anything.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Which macOS version are you using?

Comment: @HEllRZA I'm using monterey 12.5.1

Comment: Ok strange; it should be available. I am on MacOS 11, and brew even tells me that it is not compatible, and has a dependency on Xcode 13.3. I guess you already did `brew update` `brew upgrade` ... what about trying that again and then `brew search swiftlint`?

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I try to use brew doctor and follow the suggestion. The problem is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm try to use `brew doctor` and follow the suggestion, the problem is gone